# Borland C++, event functions

Tags: c++, c++builder

Can anyone tell me how do I display the calculation in the `TLabelEdit` and why can't I do the mathematics calculation? I have included `<math.h>`.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::LabelEdit1(TObject *Sender)
{
  float h;
  if (yRed == 90) {
    h = 160*4.4/(2*xRed*tan39 - 160*tan39 + 160*tan40) //cannot compile due to error
    Height->SubLabel( h );  //Is this how you write it??????

  }
}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

`tan` is a function in `math.h`. You call it like any other function. You don't just put the number after the name.

Also keep in mind that tan works on radians, not degrees, so you probably don't want the values 39 and 40 anyway.

(Also, strongly consider moving from Turbo-C++ -- it is an extremely old and poorly supported compiler)

Comment: I understand that Turbo-C++ is ancient but I'm required to used it.

Comment: @Chang: I understand that's usually why it happens and that's why I tried to answer your question, but I do feel obligated to point out things that are issues. Using Turbo-C++ is one of those issues.

Comment: @BillyONeal (s)he is not using Turbo-C++ but win32 Borland C++ Builder or newer IDE with VCL ...

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answer `tan` is function from `math.h` so you need to `#include` it and call it as function so `tan(angle)`. Beware the angle is in radians `[rad]` so you need to convert from degrees !!!

There are 2 option how to write stuff to visual components. Using `Caption` and `Text` properties. Labels,buttons,Forms etc have `Caption` , Edit boxes, memos, etc...  have `Text`.  They are strings so you need to print your number to string (you can directly assign `int,float,double,...` to it but `sprintf` is better as you can control the formatting). Here is how I see it should look like:

```cpp
#include <math.h>
const float deg=M_PI/180.0;
const int xRed=???;
const int yRed=???;
void __fastcall TForm1::LabelEdit1(TObject *Sender)
    {
    float h;
    if (yRed == 90) 
        {
        h = (160.0*4.4*tan(39.0*deg)/(2.0*float(xRed)))
          - (160.0*tan(39.0*deg))
          + (160.0*tan(40.0*deg));
        LabelEdit1->Caption=AnsiString().sprintf("h = %.3f",h);
        }
    }
```

btw. for  visual components with `Canvas` (Like Form,PaintBox,...)  you can write text directly using:

```
Canvas->TextOutA(x,y,"text");
```